# Web Api conroller is not called when async property is set to false in ajax query

Tags: javascript, ajax, crm, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api controller that is called by ajax query from my page. All works fine when the async value is set to true. When is set to false the ajax query does not fires. See below my code

C# web api controller

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using CRM_WebApp.Models;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using CRM_WebApp.Services;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CRM_WebApp.Controllers
{
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class CallBackFormController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Post([System.Web.Http.FromBody] CallBackFormModel CallBackFormModel)
    {
        ConnectiontoCrm connectiontoCrm = new ConnectiontoCrm();
        connectiontoCrm.GetConnectiontoCrmCopy();

        //Create Lead
        Entity lead = new Entity("lead");
        lead["firstname"] = CallBackFormModel.FirstName;

        return Json(new { result = "ok" });

    }
  }
}
```

Below is my ajax query

```
<script>

$("input[name='crm']").click(function(){

   var Data = {FirstName : $("input[name='user_name']").val()};

   makeAjaxCall(Data);  

  });

function makeAjaxCall(Data){
    $.ajax({

                url: "http://localhost:54360///api/CallBackForm",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(Data),

                success: function(data){

                    alert("DONESUCCESS"); 
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert("DONEERROR");
                }
            });

     }

</script>
```

I'm not sure how can i change my code to get the error

Comment: What do you see in your Network tab? Does the request get sent? Does a response come back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async:false is not a good practice. Setting async:false means you are making the process synchronous, so the browser will hang on it until it is finished -- it can't move on to your other method. Removing that option will make the call asynchronous (by default, as it should be).

if you still want to go with async:false then read the link-

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working properly, I used [Fake Online REST API](https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#how-to) from `github`

```js
(function CallTheServer() { 
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false, /* change it to true or false see the effect of alert('Check me out too'), following the ajax*/
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
              title: 'foo',
              body: 'bar',
              userId: 1
            }),
        success: function(data){
            alert("DONESUCCESS " + JSON.stringify(data)); 
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("DONEERROR");
        }
    });
    alert('Check me out too');
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```